# Convert sqlite database to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I am developing an Android application using sqlite database. I need to convert this sqlite dump to mysql using PHP which can be used in Web application. Any help will be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: what did you try? According to [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) you can dump an sqlite datase in SQL format, and that may be compatible with MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to android and sqlite. I dont know how to handle sqlite database which is to be used in Web application as mysql